# sed delete specific row

Tags: sed

Delete the string except for the beginning of NM, how should it be written with sed

input_file

```
NF
NM_001708.2(OPN1SW)
NM_000374.5(UROD)
NM_000235.4(LIPA)
NM_021828.5(HPSE2)
HPSE2, EX8-9DEL
HPSE2, EX3DEL
NM_021828.5(HPSE2)
```

output_file

```
NM_001708.2(OPN1SW)
NM_000374.5(UROD)
NM_000235.4(LIPA)
NM_021828.5(HPSE2)
NM_021828.5(HPSE2)
```

this method not what i wanted，
because ^ That means the beginning, also means the reverse
Ask how to optimize，thanks

```
sed -r '/^[^NM]/d' input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed '/^NM/!d' input_file
NM_001708.2(OPN1SW)
NM_000374.5(UROD)
NM_000235.4(LIPA)
NM_021828.5(HPSE2)
NM_021828.5(HPSE2)
```

The `!` negates the match, so this sed script deletes every line that **doesn't** begin with `NM`.    From `man sed` (GNU version):

> After the address (or address-range), and before the command, a `!`  may be inserted,
> which  specifies  that  the  command shall only be executed if the address
> (or address-range) does not match.

With `/^NM/!d`, `/^NM/` is the address (lines beginning with "NM"), and the command is `d` (delete).

---

BTW, `^` in a regular expression only means negate (or reverse in your terminology) **when it's the first character inside a bracket expression**.   Your `[^NM]` means "match all characters which aren't either N or M", not "everything which isn't N followed by M".

Comment: thankyou！
I can understand and think of this method, but can my method above be optimized?

Comment: optimised in what way?  this is about as fast as it gets - it's a simple loop over the entire input file: read a line, decide whether to delete it or not.

Comment: Modify only the expression inside the slash (/)

Comment: what? that makes no sense.

Comment: Is there any other way with sed to achieve a similar result

Comment: yes, there's probably many other ways - but you'd have to go out of your way to make it unoptimise and obscurify it.

Comment: `sed -n '/^NM/p' input_file` is probably the most obvious other way.   Instead of deleting lines not beginning with NM, it prints only the lines beginning with `NM`.  `sed`'s `-n` option only prints output when you explicitly tell it to (with the `p` command), the opposite of it's normal mode of operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with other tools you can try with `grep`

```
grep -e '^NM' input_file
```

or with `awk`

```
awk '/^NM/{print}' input_file
```

By recommendation from comment you can use with `awk`:

```
awk '/^NM/' input_file
```

Comment: You dont need to write `{print}` in awk, that's the default action when a condition is true. All you need is `awk '/^NM/' input_file`. You don't need the `-e` with grep either, just `grep '^NM' input_file`.